# Python 3 : empty list returned instead of list of words starting with vowel using comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

As I've recently started learning python 3 I came across Comprehensions which really intrigued me and I tried turning a few of my existing looping programs to loop with comprehensions. And I have been unsuccessfully trying to turn one of the programs to run with comprehension. It returns a list of words from an input list of strings, if that word starts with a vowel.

The old program which was working But without use of Python 3.0 compreshensions is given below.

```
output_list= []
list_vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
for word in input_list: 
    if word[0] in list_vowel:
        output_list.append(word)
print(output_list)
```

When I tried to write the same program using comprehension i'm getting empty list `[]`  everytime i run the code whether the i/p list is `['a','e','i','o','u'] or ["aeiou"] etc`

The code with usage of comprehension is given below

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

output_list = []
list_vowel = ["aeiou"]
output_list = [ x for x in input_list if x[0] in list_vowel ]
# for i in list_vowel if x[0] == list_vowel[i]]
print(output_list)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Or if there exist cases where we can't use python comprehensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works if you replace `list_vowel = ["aeiou"]` with `list_vowel = "aeiou"` or `list_vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']`. `"a"` is not in `["aeiou"]` because the only element in that iterable is `"aeiou"`.

Comment: I retried in jupyter with ``` list_vowel = "aeiou" & list_vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u'] ``` but got the following error msg
``` Traceback (most recent call last):

 
  File "<ipython-input-27-30e0046284ff>", line 3, in <module>
    input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

 ..
  File "/home/abhi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line unknown
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing ```

Comment: that worked in a different compiler. thanks, maybe something wrong with jupyter notebook.